# Application error in Windows event log, faulting module name is unknow, why?

Tags: windows, module, crash, event-log

Why the Faulting module name is unknown here?

```
Faulting application name: myapp.exe, version: 15.0.4128.1014, time stamp: 0x4fe548d7
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000
Faulting process id: 0x1074
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd67adc0cf5f95
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\myapp.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: fe9a7f10-d3a0-11e1-af1c-0050b653a9a0
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way that the faulting module could be *known* is when the exception is caused by executing code in a memory address that "belongs" to a particular module (Probably based on the module's loaded address).

So one way that the module could be *unknown* is if an application is dereferencing a pointer that is NULL or contains random data. That way it will attempt to execute code from some undefined location that cannot be tied to a particular module.